# Unable to send object from Jquery(Ajax) call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mongodb, mlab

I am trying to send data to MongoLab DB using JS+ JqueryAjax call.
My problem is i am able to see the OID in DB but no Data is populated.
When checked in code , Network settings my payload is always empty.
I am unable to figure out why my object is misbehaving.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Boom!</title>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Stuff.</h1>
        <p>
            <button class="btn btn-large">Press Me!</button>

        </p>
        <form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform"  method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value =""/> <br/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"  id="lname" value ="" /> <br/>
</form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
    <script>
        var stuff = {
            run: function () {
                $('button').bind('click', function () {
                    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
                        var geo_options = {
                            name: fname.value ,
                            surname: lname.value

                        };
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(stuff.send, stuff.error, geo_options);
              window.alert(geo_options.fname);
              document.write(geo_options.fname.value);
              console.log(geo_options.fname.value);

                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            },
            send: function (object) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/geolocation/collections/boom?apiKey=[apiKey]",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify( object ),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }).done(function( msg ) {
                    console.log(msg);
                });
            }
        };
        $(function() {
            stuff.run();
        });
    </script>
```

I always see my object as undefines in popups and console. I have just started using JS and Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

`fname` and `lname` are not defined. To access their values, you need to use these two functions: `$("#fname").val()` and `$("#lname").val()`. I'm surprised you're getting undefined in your console instead of an error.

And when you try to access those value in `geo_options`, you aren't using the right keys. `window.alert(geo_options.fname);` should be `window.alert(geo_options.name);`

I would also keep the run, error and send functions outside of the object `stuff`, as there seems to be no need for it. And I think those functions may need to be inside of the document ready snippet (what you have at the bottom) for the selectors to be guaranteed to work, but I'm not sure.